# How can i store and show only the last 5 NEWS seen by the current user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app who has several section such as news, posts, jobs, events etc. All of that with a working register/login system.

The News section displays all of the news available to see and has a little div that it shows RECENT ACTIVITY

the RECENT ACTIVITY div is supposed to Show only the last 5 news that the current user have seen in that session.

I managed to show the last 5 url the current user have seen but i want to limit that to only the news controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

   before_filter :store_recent_news

private

  def store_recent_news
    session[:recents] ||= []
    session[:recents].delete_at(0) if session[:recents].size >= 5
    session[:recents] << request.url
  end
```

In the recent activity div i will ONLY show the last 5 news 
right now i show a list like this:

-localhost:3000/news/17

-localhost:3000/news

-localhost:3000/jobs/29

-localhost:3000/jobs

-localhost:3000/directory

I want to display only the links to the last news seen by the current user, something like

link to news2

link to news5

link to news3

I hope i make myself clear about what's the problem and what i want to do.

ok i managed to get the ID of the last 5 news visited by the current user

```
 before_filter :recently_viewed, only: [:show, :index]


      def recently_viewed
        (session[:Directory_id] ||= []) << params[:id]
        session[:Directory_id].delete_at(0) if session[:Directory_id].size >= 10
      end
```

Now I managed to display the last 5 ID of the news the current user have visited on the session,  but i need to display the name of the news as a link. any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. If you want it to happen for only `News` resources, why don't you just put your code into `news_controller` rather than `application_controller`? (By the way, storing `News` id's in your session is a better idea than storing the whole URL of the request.)

Comment: even if i do i'm only storing the url of any page i visit as the user, but i want to limit that to only store if the view visited is from the news contoller.

Comment: Put your code to `news_controller`. And edit before filter like this: `before_filter :store_recent_news, only: [:show]`

Comment: ty i did change the code to my news controller and it works fine just one thing to go display links correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  before_filter :recently_viewed_contacts

  def recently_viewed_contacts
    session[:New_id] ||= []
    session[:New_id] << params[:id] unless params[:id].nil?
    session[:New_id].delete_at(0) if session[:News_id].size >= 4
  end
```

So I figure out how to do it with the same array Approach just change the parameter to only check for the news matching id's and a put a little correction for the nil getting by refresh or checking other views different from news.

```
  def index
    @recent_news = session[:News_id]
    @news = User.approved.order(:name).page(params[:page]).per(8)
  end
```

And used the new array for displaying the title of the last 5 news visited by the user

```
        <% @recent_news.each do |recent| %>
          <p><%= New.find(recent).title %></p>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a scope in your news model:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

```
scope :recent_news, order("created_at desc").limit(5)
```

Then, in your `news_controller`, on whatever action you need, you have access to this custom query:

```
def index
  # whatever
  @recent_news = News.recent_news
end
```

Then you can use the instance variable in the correspondent view.

Comment: ty for answering, but that will only give the last created news i need the last news visited by the current user.