# List only the last 5 articles seen by current user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following this stackoverflow post, [How can i store and show only the last 5 NEWS seen by the current user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944637/how-can-i-store-and-show-only-the-last-5-news-seen-by-the-current-user)

However, i think I am getting this error (Couldn't find Article with 'id'=python-0), because I'm using friendly_id gem to generate the article url. Is there a workaround for this?

Application controller

```
  before_action :recently_viewed_articles

  def recently_viewed_articles
    session[:article_id] ||= []
    session[:article_id] << params[:id] unless params[:id].nil?
    session[:article_id].delete_at(0) if session[:article_id].size >= 5
  end
```

Pages Controller

```
def home
    @recent_articles = session[:article_id]
    @feed = current_user.feed
end
```

_feed.html.erb

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-9">
        <%= render @feed %>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-3">
      <div class="list-group">
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
            Recently visited
          </button>
        <% @recent_articles.each do |recent| %>
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            <%= link_to "#{Article.find(recent).title}", article_path(Article.find(recent)) %>
          </button>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation, I believe you should be using `friendly` scope.

```
Article.friendly.find(recent)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Have you set everything up as you should do? If you haven't, then you can use:

```
Article.friendly.find('python-0')
```

Otherwise, in your article model:

```
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```

Then you can call

```
Article.find('python-0')
```